# JQuery proxy on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, proxy

Here is the scenario. I want to customize the built in plugin. Here is the scenario of default functionality.

**Current Scenario by default**

There are list if thumbnail images and when I click on an image then it just gets inserted in the area. Please see the default code below.

**Code by default**

```
var img = $('<img src="' + val.thumb + '" />');
$(img).click($.proxy(this.imageThumbClick, this));
imageThumbClick: function (e) {
        var img = '<img id="image-marker" src="' + $(e.target).attr('rel') + '" alt="' + $(e.target).attr('title') + '" />';
        var parent = this.getParent();
        if (this.opts.paragraphy && $(parent).closest('li').size() == 0) img = '<p>' + img + '</p>';
        this.imageInsert(img, true); // insert an image
    }
```

**My requirement**

I want if I click on any thumbnail then it should mark selected and then if i click on button "insert image" then the selected image should insert. but my code is not working. Can you please help me to achieve my goal

**My customized code**

```
var img = $('<img src="' + val.thumb + '" />');
var thisImg;
 $(img).click(function () {
     $('img').removeClass('checked');
     $(this).addClass('checked');
     thisImg = $(this);
 });
 $('#insert-btn').click(function () {
     thisImg.imageThumbClick();
 });
imageThumbClick: function (e) {
    var img = '<img id="image-marker" src="' + $(e.target).attr('rel') + '" alt="' + $(e.target).attr('title') + '" />';
    var parent = this.getParent();
    if (this.opts.paragraphy && $(parent).closest('li').size() == 0) img = '<p>' + img + '</p>';
    this.imageInsert(img, true); // insert an image
}
```

Comment: what is not working? is there an error?

Comment: @reyaner, yes the error is this on the cosole "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageThumbClick' of undefined" "(anonymous function) jQuery.event.dispatch elemData.handle"

Comment: Well that would make sense. In your code your using `imageThumbClick` like an object function, but, unless there's some code we're not seeing, it's not inside an object.