# calling a function using $.proxy javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, proxy

I want to load a function on click event using $.proxy.
If i load the function using the below click event then everything works fine.

**click event which is working**

```
$('element').click($.proxy(this.doProcess, this));
```

**click event which is not working**

```
$('element').click(function(){
    // Perform other things
    $.proxy(this.doProcess, this);  
});
```

As you can see that i want to perform other things on the click event before loading the function. Can you please help me figure out why it is not loading if i use ".click(function()..." instead of simply '.click()..'

Answer (score 1):

Because in the first snippet the click function calls the returned function. In the second snippet you are binding the current `this` value to the function, but you don't call the returned function. You can use the invocation operator (`()`) for calling the function:

```
$.proxy(this.doProcess, this)();
```

Note that `this` in the context of the anonymous function (which is the current event handler) doesn't refer to the `this` keyword's value of the outer context, you can cache the value:

```
var that = this;
$('element').click(function() {
    // Perform other things
    $.proxy(that.doProcess, this)(/* arguments go here */);  
//           |               |
//           |               ----- refers to the clicked element
//           ----- reference of the outer context's `this` value
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I tried that but it didn't load the function doProcess

Comment: @mak You are welcome, I have created a demo on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Lnxmg5ub/

Comment: Actually I am using a third party plugin and i want to customize the functionality based on the requirement. is there anyway if i can send you the code file in your email? you just point out the issue?

Comment: @mak Well, that requires reverse engineering and possibly dedicating too much time, I'd be happy if I could help you, but unfortunately I'm quite busy right now. I'd suggest porting another question if there is a new problem.

Comment: I had created the question on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937102/jquery-proxy-on-click-function. So it is related to this topic. This functionality is working fine when using simple click but If am doing click function then doesn't work. I have even tried your suggestion above as well. Any thought?